# Stuck with Prolog Program

Tags: prolog

I am fluent with Java and C#, so coding in Prolog has been quite a struggle for me so far as it seems to be a completely different way of thinking.

The problem I need to solve is simple, and I could crank it out in Java in ten minutes. I'm just honestly having trouble even getting started here. I am given a list of ten numbers that represent a voters "votes". A vote is either a 0, -1, or 1. Then I am also given a list of lists, each list is a list for a Candidate. The list for each Candidate includes a name, followed by ten scores like that in the Voter list.

My goal is to then compare the Voter list with each Candidate list and return a list of the best matches, based on the votes that are the same.

This is what I am given:

```
?- best_candidates(
    [           0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   1],
    [[adams     1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
     [grant    -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1],
     [polk      1,  -1,   1,  -1,   1,  -1,   1,  -1,   1,  -1],
     [jackson   1,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0],
     [taft      0,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1],
     [ford      1,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
     [madison   0,   0,   0,   1,  -1,   0,   0,  -1,   1,   1]],
    BestMatches).
```

This should return BestMatches = [adams, ford, madison].

So far I don't have much. I'm just trying to figure out how I should do this. Am I going to need multiple methods, or should I be able to do this all within the best_candidates method?

In reponse to Edmund's suggestion, here is what I have thus far:

```
% match V1 and V2 and unify M with the match score
% match(V1, V2, M)
match([], [], 0).
match([H1|T1], [H2|T2], M) :-
    match_single_entry(H1, H2, M1),
    match(T1, T2, M2), 
    M is M1+M2.

% match_single_entry(I, J, M)
match_single_entry(X, Y, M) :-
    X =\= 0,
    Y =\= 0,
    I =:= J, 
    M is 1.
```

Comment: 1)  Why would it return those three?  Adams and Ford make sense but Madison, not so much.  2)  Prolog is different than any other language you've encountered; you simply must *tell it what is true about your universe*.  You then query and/or write functions to ascertain the truth from your universe.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to mention that the only scores that actually count towards the similar score count are the ones that are nonzero.

Comment: With user1704677's clarification to my answer, I get 1 for each of those three and less for the others.

Comment: You will also need to add rules to `match_single_entry` for the cases where X = 0 or Y = 0, or X \= Y, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the crux of the problem is a function that takes two vectors of 10 numbers, and returns a total match score.

The first thing is Prolog doesn't have functions; it has predicates.  But you can easily translate the function concept into the predicate concept, by providing variables that can be bound to the outputs of the "function":

```
% Match V1 and V2, and unify M with the match score.
match(V1, V2, M) :- ...
```

It's not clear exactly how the vectors are matched (but I think it's the number of identical entries?  or the sum of the absolute differences between each pair of entries?).  But this predicate will likely be defined with a base case (for lists of length 0), and a general case that computes it for the heads of each list, and the recurses on the tail of the lists.

```
match([], [], 0).  % I'm assuming the match score for empty lists is 0.
match([H1|T1], [H2|T2], M) :-
    match_single_entry(H1, H2, M1),  % Somehow compute the score for two single entries.
    match(T1, T2, M2),  % Recurse on the tails.
    M is M1+M2.  % Combine the two scores and bind to the output variable M.
```

I've left `match_single_entry` undefined.  Once you define it, you should practice running `match` with various candidates' vectors against the voter's vector:

```
% Let's try getting the match score for adams:
?- match([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1], AdamsScore).

AdamsScore = 3 ;

No
```

The next challenge is to write another predicate `best_candidates` that takes the voter's vector plus the set of candidate vectors, scores each one, and returns -- that is, binds to the output variable corresponding to `BestMatches` -- those that score best.  Again, this predicate could iterate over the set of candidate vectors by defining a base case (no candidates, and hence no best ones), and a recursive case that handles one candidate at a time.

### Scoring each candidate vector

As you mention, a candidate vector has a name followed by the values.  This means the vector can easily be split by `[Name|Values] = V`, and `Values` can be passed to `match` to compare against the voter vector.

The other thing is storing the names in the `BestMatches` list.  The `best_candidates` predicate has to score each candidate vector, keeping those scores somewhere, and then it has to find the best score, and then it has to go through the original candidate names and add those which are as good as the best score.

It's suggest adding a predicate to do the first part:

```
% Score all vectors, returning a list of scores.
% score_vectors(VoterVector, AllVectors, AllScores)
score_vectors(V, [], []).
score_vectors(V, [H|T], [SH, ST]) :-
    ... score V against H, matching the result against SH.
    ... recurse on T and ST.
```

(Fill in the two lines with `...`)  Then use a simple predicate to find the maximum score from `AllScores` (or there might a builtin predicate to do it).

Then make another predicate which iterates over all the vectors and scores, and picks those which meet the best score:

```
% Pick best candidates.
% pick_best(AllVectors, AllScores, BestScore, BestNames).
pick_best([], [], BS, []).
pick_best([H|T], [SH|ST], BS, [Name|NT]) :-
    H = [Name|Values],
    SH >= BS.
pick_best([H|T], [SH|ST], BS, NT) :-
    H = [Name|Values],
    SH < BS.
```

Then build `best_candidates` out of these three steps:

```
best_candidates(VoterVector, CandidateVectors, BestNames) :-
    score_vectors(VoterVector, CandidateVectors, Scores),
    maximum(Scores, BestScore),
    pick_best(CandidateVectors, Scores, BestScore, BestNames).
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very, very helpful. The logic behind determining the number for each candidate is as follows...

Comment: agreement_score = (the number of questions for which the voter and the candidate gave the same nonzero answer) - (the number of questions for which the voter and the candidate gave different nonzero answers)

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  In that case, `match_single_entry(X,Y, M)` could bind `M = 1` if `X` and `Y` are nonzero and the same, or `M = -1` if they're nonzero and different.  Otherwise if one is zero then `M = 0`.  Do you know how to write `match_single_entry` that way?

Comment: Really having trouble getting this code to show up in a code block... lol.. this is what I have come up with so far.

Comment: Ah ok... I stuck what I have so far at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I'm really stuck with two parts now. For each Candidate list, the list starts with the name of the Candidate. This throws things off since it technically holds eleven values unlike the Voter list which holds 10, all scores. I'm also not sure how I'm going to actually store the name of the Candidate into the BestMatches list.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show a solution implemented with the help of SWI-Prolog library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)).

```
:- [library(aggregate)].

best_candidates(Votes, Candidates, Best) :-
    maplist(count_matched(Votes), Candidates, NamesCounted),
    keysort(NamesCounted, BestDown),
    reverse(BestDown, Best).

count_matched(Votes, [Name|ThisVotes], MatchCount-Name) :-
    aggregate_all(sum(V * T),
        ( nth1(I, Votes, V),
          nth1(I, ThisVotes, T)
        ), MatchCount).

test(BestMatches) :-
    best_candidates(
         [           0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   1],
        [[adams   ,  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
         [grant   , -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1],
         [polk    ,  1,  -1,   1,  -1,   1,  -1,   1,  -1,   1,  -1],
         [jackson ,  1,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0],
         [taft    ,  0,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1,   0,  -1],
         [ford    ,  1,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
         [madison ,  0,   0,   0,   1,  -1,   0,   0,  -1,   1,   1]],
        BestMatches),
    BestMatches = [_-A, _-B, _-C|_],
    writeln([A, B, C]).
```

test output:

```
?- test(L).
[madison,ford,adams]
L = [1-madison, 1-ford, 1-adams, -1-jackson, -1-grant, -2-taft, -3-polk].
```